# How to start an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created two classes: `Example1` and `Example2`, which extends activity.
`Example1` contains a UI of buttons, while Example2 contains UI of TextEdit. I want to call Example2 when a button is clicked, so this code is in an `onclick` method

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.a.ui", "com.a.ui.Example2");
startActivity(i);
```

So I am able to get the UI of Example2 successfully. What's an alternate way of calling intent?

Is there any alternate way to start an activity?

Comment: is there any specific needs for this?

Comment: actually to use stgartActivity() method I have to use it inside any class which extends Activity. But I want to call it from a class which dooesnot intent Activity class.

Comment: you need a context to start an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(com.a.ui.this, com.a.ui.Example2.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(com.a.ui.this, com.a.ui.Example2.class);
  startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

And remember to include the Activity in your Manifest.xml

e.g.

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```